# Upgrading from Apache Camel 3.16.0 to 3.17.0 - Failed to load ApplicationContext

Tags: java, spring-boot, type-conversion, apache-camel, upgrade

A lot of unit tests failed when upgrading a Springboot application from Apache Camel 3.16.0 to 3.17.0

All the test that failed has the following annotation:

```
@SpringBootTest
```

All the tests that passed doesnt have @SpringBootTest annotation or has it with specific classes like:

```
@SpringBootTest(classes = {JacksonAutoConfiguration.class, CamelAutoConfiguration.class})
```

I have following camel springboot dependencies

```
compile "org.apache.camel.springboot:camel-spring-boot-dependencies:${camelVersion}"
compile "org.apache.camel.springboot:camel-spring-boot-starter:${camelVersion}"
compile "org.apache.camel.springboot:camel-core-starter:${camelVersion}"
```

CamelContext is autowired in them

```
@Autowired
CamelContext camelContext
```

I also added the following before using camelContext object, but I guess the issue is happening when Spring does autowire

```
context.setStreamCaching(false);
```

As per documentation: https://camel.apache.org/manual/camel-3x-upgrade-guide-3_17.html, StreamCahcing is enabled by default. So I disabled it using the following property in appication.properties file, but it didnt help.

```
camel.springboot.streamCachingEnabled=false
```

```
Failed to load ApplicationContext
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:132)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:124)
    at org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.setUpRequestContextIfNecessary(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:190)
    at org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:132)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:248)
    at org.spockframework.spring.SpringTestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(SpringTestContextManager.java:56)
    at org.spockframework.spring.SpringInterceptor.interceptInitializerMethod(SpringInterceptor.java:46)
    at org.spockframework.runtime.extension.AbstractMethodInterceptor.intercept(AbstractMethodInterceptor.java:24)
    at org.spockframework.runtime.extension.MethodInvocation.proceed(MethodInvocation.java:101)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$prepare$1(NodeTestTask.java:111)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.prepare(NodeTestTask.java:111)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:79)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1541)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:143)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:129)
    at org.spockframework.runtime.model.MethodInfo.invoke(MethodInfo.java:148)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:127)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:126)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:84)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1541)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:143)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:129)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:127)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:126)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:84)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:32)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:57)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:51)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:108)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:88)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.lambda$execute$0(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:54)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.withInterceptedStreams(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:67)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:52)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:96)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:75)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor$CollectAllTestClassesExecutor.processAllTestClasses(JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor.java:99)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor$CollectAllTestClassesExecutor.access$000(JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor.java:79)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor.stop(JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor.java:75)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.SuiteTestClassProcessor.stop(SuiteTestClassProcessor.java:61)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:36)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ContextClassLoaderDispatch.dispatch(ContextClassLoaderDispatch.java:33)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ProxyDispatchAdapter$DispatchingInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyDispatchAdapter.java:94)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker.stop(TestWorker.java:133)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:36)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
    at org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.hub.MessageHubBackedObjectConnection$DispatchWrapper.dispatch(MessageHubBackedObjectConnection.java:182)
    at org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.hub.MessageHubBackedObjectConnection$DispatchWrapper.dispatch(MessageHubBackedObjectConnection.java:164)
    at org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.hub.MessageHub$Handler.run(MessageHub.java:414)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:64)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:48)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:56)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'handler1': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.ConversionNotSupportedException: Failed to convert property value of type 'org.apache.camel.processor.errorhandler.RedeliveryPolicy' to required type 'org.apache.camel.model.RedeliveryPolicyDefinition' for property 'redeliveryPolicy'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type 'org.apache.camel.processor.errorhandler.RedeliveryPolicy' to required type 'org.apache.camel.model.RedeliveryPolicyDefinition' for property 'redeliveryPolicy': no matching editors or conversion strategy found
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:628)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:953)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:918)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:775)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:448)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:339)
    at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader.loadContext(SpringBootContextLoader.java:144)
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:99)
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:124)
    ... 62 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.ConversionNotSupportedException: Failed to convert property value of type 'org.apache.camel.processor.errorhandler.RedeliveryPolicy' to required type 'org.apache.camel.model.RedeliveryPolicyDefinition' for property 'redeliveryPolicy'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type 'org.apache.camel.processor.errorhandler.RedeliveryPolicy' to required type 'org.apache.camel.model.RedeliveryPolicyDefinition' for property 'redeliveryPolicy': no matching editors or conversion strategy found
    at org.springframework.beans.AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.convertIfNecessary(AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.java:595)
    at org.springframework.beans.AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.convertForProperty(AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.java:609)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.convertForProperty(BeanWrapperImpl.java:219)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.convertForProperty(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1756)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1712)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1452)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:619)
    ... 76 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type 'org.apache.camel.processor.errorhandler.RedeliveryPolicy' to required type 'org.apache.camel.model.RedeliveryPolicyDefinition' for property 'redeliveryPolicy': no matching editors or conversion strategy found
    at org.springframework.beans.TypeConverterDelegate.convertIfNecessary(TypeConverterDelegate.java:262)
    at org.springframework.beans.AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.convertIfNecessary(AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.java:590)
    ... 82 more
```

I appreciate any solution/suggestion. Thank you

Comment: Maybe generate a new spring-boot camel project using archetype `camel-archetype-spring-boot` and see how it has been setup and if you're missing something. I would also recommend upgrading straight to LTS release 3.18.x or 3.20.x instead as 3.17.x releases are no longer receiving updates.

Comment: Thank you for responding. I posted the solution that worked for me. The plan is to upgrade to 3.20. I was incrementing each version to narrow down the changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have the following configuration for DeadLetter channel, set the redelivery policy object.

```
deadLetterChannelBuilder = BeanDefinitionBuilder.genericBeanDefinition(DeadLetterChannelBuilder.class)
                    .addPropertyValue("redeliveryPolicy", createRedeliveryPolicy(handlerProperties))
```

I had the following method to set the required redelivery policy properties and return the RedeliveryPolicy object

```
private RedeliveryPolicy createRedeliveryPolicy(HandlerProperties handlerProperties) {
        RedeliveryPolicy redeliveryPolicy = new RedeliveryPolicy();
        redeliveryPolicy.setMaximumRedeliveries(handlerProperties.getRedeliveryPolicy().getMaximumRedeliveries());
        redeliveryPolicy.setRedeliveryDelay(handlerProperties.getRedeliveryPolicy().getRedeliveryDelay());
        redeliveryPolicy.setUseCollisionAvoidance(handlerProperties.getRedeliveryPolicy().getUseCollisionAvoidance());
        return redeliveryPolicy;
    }
```

The issue is resolved when I replaced RedeliveryPolicy with RedeliveryPolicyDefinition object as follows.

```
    private RedeliveryPolicyDefinition createRedeliveryPolicy(HandlerProperties handlerProperties) {

        RedeliveryPolicyDefinition redeliveryPolicyDef = new RedeliveryPolicyDefinition()
                .maximumRedeliveries(handlerProperties.getRedeliveryPolicy().getMaximumRedeliveries())
                .redeliveryDelay(handlerProperties.getRedeliveryPolicy().getRedeliveryDelay());

        if(handlerProperties.getRedeliveryPolicy().getUseCollisionAvoidance()){
            redeliveryPolicyDef.useCollisionAvoidance();
        }
        return redeliveryPolicyDef;
    }
```

Somehow, RedeliveryPolicy object is replaced by RedeliveryPolicyDefinition when switching from Camel 3.16.0 to 3.17.0 version, but I couldnt find any mention of it in the Camel upgrade documentation.

I hope it helps others facing this issue.